Include memory vectorstore to RunnableSequence in Langchain?
I am creating a chat UI that takes the user input + attachments; the attachments are converted into <Document<Record<string, any>>[]> through a custom function I created, which turns the document into Blobloader. I can usually convert this, but my issue is passing the document array to the agent.
Define Model:
I have defined my model to use GPT-3.5 and to respond in the stream.

    const model = new ChatOpenAI({
      openAIApiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_OPENAI_API_KEY as string,
      model: import.meta.env.VIRE_OPENAI_MODEL as string,
      streaming: true,
      temperature: 0,
    });

Define Tools:
I have a set of tools that the AI relies on to answer some questions.
    const tools = [
      ToolOne(),
      ToolTwo(),
    ];

Prompt Template
I created a prompt template that takes the user input and context (which is the context of the document). Later, we used createStuffDocumentsChain to satisfy this input. Of course, the chat_history (to include previous messages) and agent_scratchpad for the agent were also created.
    const prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages([
      ['system', Prompts()],
      new MessagesPlaceholder('chat_history'),
      ['human', '{input}'],
      ['human', '{context}'],
      new MessagesPlaceholder('agent_scratchpad'),
    ]);

Bind Tools to the Model
    const openAIWithFunction = model.bind({
      functions: tools.map((tool) => convertToOpenAIFunction(tool)),
    });

Embedding & Vector Storing of Documents
I create a chain with createStuffDocumentsChain to include OpenAIWithFunction with my tools and documents. I convert the document's context to a vector stored in memory. Hint: the docLoaders variable is the document chunks. Then, I make a retrieval chain.
    const documentChain = await createStuffDocumentsChain({
      llm: openAIWithFunction,
      prompt,
    });

    const vectorstores = await MemoryVectorStore.fromDocuments(
      docLoaders,
      new OpenAIEmbeddings({
        model: 'text-embedding-3-small',
        openAIApiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_OPENAI_API_KEY as string,
      })
    );

    const retriver = vectorstores.asRetriever({
      k: 2,
    });


    const retrivalChain = await createRetrievalChain({
      combineDocsChain: documentChain,
      retriever: retriver,
    });

Creating Agent
Finally, we pass the retrieval chain to RunnableSequence and create the agent.
    const runnableAgent = RunnableSequence.from([
      {
        input: (i) => i.input,
        context: (i) => i.context,
        agent_scratchpad: (i) => formatToOpenAIFunctionMessages(i.steps),
        chat_history: (i) => i.chat_history,
      },
      prompt,
      retrivalChain,
      new OpenAIFunctionsAgentOutputParser(),
    ]);

    const TestAgent = AgentExecutor.fromAgentAndTools({
      returnIntermediateSteps: true,
      agent: runnableAgent,
      tools,
    }).withConfig({
      runName: 'Test Agent',
    });

Execute
When I execute, I receive an error.
    console.log(
      'Agent',
      await TestAgent.invoke({
        input: `What is the content of this document?`,
        chat_history: chatHistory,
      })
    );

Error

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
at OpenAIEmbeddings.embedQuery (@langchain_openai.js?v=88216997:7255:40)
at _MemoryVectorStore.similaritySearch (chunk-FEMVUZ4L.js?v=88216997:173:86)
at VectorStoreRetriever._getRelevantDocuments (chunk-FEMVUZ4L.js?v=88216997:144:29)
at VectorStoreRetriever.getRelevantDocuments (chunk-FEMVUZ4L.js?v=88216997:72:34)
at async VectorStoreRetriever._streamIterator (chunk-SP3I4EZH.js?v=88216997:6539:5)
at async VectorStoreRetriever.transform (chunk-SP3I4EZH.js?v=88216997:6745:5)
at async _RunnableSequence._streamIterator (chunk-SP3I4EZH.js?v=88216997:7385:24)
at async _RunnableSequence.transform (chunk-SP3I4EZH.js?v=88216997:6745:5)
at async _RunnableBinding.transform (chunk-SP3I4EZH.js?v=88216997:7061:5)

